# How to generate csr for a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, csr, namecheap

**Problem description**

I've faced a problem with setting up ssl. I need to send a csr to namecheap for registering ssl.

I went to [namecheap guidline for generating csr](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/467/67/how-to-generate-csr-certificate-signing-request-code) and I found no information about spring-boot applications.

**Question**

Is there any way to generate it for spring-boot?

**Supposed solution**

As I know spring-boot uses tomcat as an application server, so probably I need to use [guide for tomcat](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9422/14/generating-a-csr-on-tomcat-using-a-keytool). But I'm not sure in that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the guide for Tomcat. There is nothing specific about Spring Boot that you need to worry about for an SSL certificate.